# How to generate default MenuItem template in Blend 2015?

Tags: c#, xaml, blend

In Blend 2013, I was able to right-click on MenuItem, select Edit a Copy and then generate the appropriate (large!) template for MenuItem. It starts with:

`<ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">`

and looks like

[image]

Also I was able to select "Apply to all".

[image]

In Blend 2015, when I attempt to do the same thing, I get a truncated MenuItem Control Template that not only doesn't quite work right, but requires an x:Key

[image]

and Apply to all cannot be selected.

[image]

*Update.* Sadly, but not surprisingly this is also seen in the XAML editor in VS2015.
*Update2.* Wonder if this has something to do with 2015 creating a ControlTemplate instead of a Style for the MenuItem.

---

*Update3.* If you generate the template from Blend 2013 and put it in Blend 2014, you can no longer display the XAML in the editor 

`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate'.`

Is the error you get. I suspect that when the testers saw this, rather than fixing it, they abandoned giving access to the whole MenuItem template and replaced it with the current (which completely fails to handle submenus, etc.).

In case anyone else runs into this, the problem comes from ComponentResourceKey. When TypeInTargetAssembly is set, the error occurs... the line looks like

`x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}"`

If TypeInTargetAssembly is taken out, the XAML preview will work. However, the template will not be applied.